# Change language when button pressed Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multilingual

I want to make my app multi-language. I know how to do this.
But the problem is that, the user should first change the phones languages before the translation will work.

What I want to do is the following: I have 3 buttons. Dutch,English,French. 
When a user presses a button. The language of the app is changed to the appropriate language. But the phone's language keeps the same.

Hope anyone can help me!

Kind regards

Comment: I think you cannot change the language of the whole system from an app... This operation should be handle only by the Settings.app.

Comment: He does not want to change the language of the whole system. He only wants to change the language of the app.

Comment: i think manually you can set the text/data related to language selection.. maintaining the data in some plists...

Comment: Yes I only want to change the language in app itself

Comment: @Steaphann did you get any solution for this ..same thing i need .plz let me know if you have solution

Answer (score 0):

But the different translations into different files. Load the needed file according to the button the user touched.

If this does not answer your question, please be more specific what exactly you problem is.

Comment: I have a localizable.strings(Dutch) and a localizable.string(English) file. Each with key-value coding of my labels. How to I load this up when a button is pressed ?